# Error adding web test in microsoft application insights

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I am creating a new web test in microsoft application insights. It is a multi-step web test, so I have recorded the test in visual studio. When I try to upload the .webtest extension file, I get below error .

> Creating web test "test" failed with error:"Specified argument was out
>   of the range of valid values. Parameter name: Visual Studio Web Test
>   (Id = 'application_test-web.core app_us-tx-sn1-azr') has no items.
>   Visual Studio Web Test (Id = 'application_test-web.core
>   app_us-il-ch1-azr') has no items. Visual Studio Web Test (Id =
>   'application_test-web.core app_us-ca-sjc-azr') has no items. Visual
>   Studio Web Test (Id = 'application_test-web.core app_us-va-ash-azr')
>   has no items. Visual Studio Web Test (Id = 'application_test-web.core
>   app_us-fl-mia-edge') has no items.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually happens when the web test does not have any requests in it. You can open the .webtest file up in notepad and verify you see at least one "Request" tag under "Items".

Comment: yes, you are right. I dont see any tag in the .webtest file. I will create a new test and try again.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.